# Setting up a LVS on CentOS

Tags: centos, lvs, piranha, ipvs

I have a 3 node(dedicated servers from a provider) CentOS 7.x cluster. I am trying to set up LVS using the link [here](http://dak1n1.com/blog/13-load-balancing-lvs).

Each of my machines already has 3 extra alias IP addresses assigned to it. I want to set up the LVS on one of these machines. My question is what should I use as the Virtual IP(VIP) in the Piranha Configuration Tool? Can I pick up one of the alias IPs for that machine that I want the LVS to be on?

Comment: On the CentOS 7.0 there aren't pulse and piranha, you need to use keepalived and haproxy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to choose a different IP address for your VIP.

For example if you have 3 real servers with ips 192.168.0.11,192.168.0.12, 192.168.0.13 you would like to use 192.168.0.10 as your VIP.

So you have to configure the VIP on each server.

```
 /sbin/ip addr add 192.168.100.30 dev eth1
```

You can follow this link if you want:

> http://kezhong.wordpress.com/2010/03/28/setup-linux-loadbalancer-with-piranha-and-lvs-on-centos-5-4/

Here comes the text of the tutorial (:

> #### Test environment:

```
LVS Router 1: eth0: 192.168.26.201
LVS Router 2: eth0: 192.168.26.202
Real Server 1: eth0: 192.168.26.211
Real Server 2: eth0: 192.168.26.212       
VIP: 192.168.26.200
gateway: 192.168.26.1
```

> #### Install piranha and ipvsadm packages on the LVS Routers

```
# yum install ipvsadm
# yum install piranha
```

> #### Configure Services on the LVS Routers

```
# chkconfig pulse on
# chkconfig piranha-gui on
# chkconfig httpd on
```

> #### Set a Password for the Piranha Configuration Tool

```
# piranha-passwd
```

> #### Turn on Packet Forwarding on the LVS Routers

```
# echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

> #### Start the Piranha Configuration Tool Service
>
> Change the SELinux mode to **permissive**. If you didn’t do it, it would show the error message as below when you start the `piranha-gui` service.
>
> > Starting piranha-gui: (13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:3636
> >        (13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:3636
> >        No listening sockets available, shutting down
> >        Unable to open logs

```
# setenforce 0
# service httpd start
# service piranha-gui start
```

> #### Configure the LVS Routers with Piranha Configuration Tool
>
> Open http://`192`.`168`.`26`.`201`:3636 in a Web browser to access the Piranha Configuration Tool. Click on the Login button and enter piranha for the Username and the administrative password you created in the Password field.
>
> Click on the GLOBAL SETTINGS panel, and input the primary server public IP, and then click the ACCEPT button.
>
> Click on the REDUNDANCY panel, and input the redundant server public IP, and then click the ACCEPT button.
>
> Click on the VIRTUAL SERVERS panel, add a server, edit it, and activate it.
>
> Clicking on the REAL SERVER subsection link at the top of the panel displays the EDIT REAL SERVER subsection. Click the ADD button to add new servers, edit them and activate them.
>
> #### Copy the lvs.cf file to another LVS router.

```
# scp /etc/sysconfig/ha/lvs.cf root@192.168.26.202:/etc/sysconfig/ha/lvs.cf
```

> #### Start the pulse services on the LVS Routers

```
# service pulse restart
```